# std::shared_ptr::use_count() gives different result when partly cross compiled

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling, shared-ptr

I have a situation with shared_ptr lifetime and cross compilation that I can't make sense of. Given the following files with content:

a.hpp

```
#ifndef LIBA
#define LIBA    
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<std::string> createShared();

#endif
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.hpp"
#include <iostream>

std::shared_ptr<std::string> createShared(){
    static std::shared_ptr<std::string> member = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello");
    std::cout << "use count " << member.use_count() << std::endl;
    return member;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "a.hpp"

int main(int, char**) {
    auto value = createShared();
    std::cout << "use count " << value.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value: " << *value<< std::endl;
}
```

I can simply compile it either on my computer or my raspberry pi using

```
g++ main.cpp a.cpp
```

Running the resulting a.out gives

```
use count 1
use count 2
value: Hello
```

Which is what I would expect.
But if I instead choose to cross compile a.cpp, things change.

So on my computer I run

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c a.cpp
```

Then I scp the result a.o to my raspberry pi, where I run

```
g++ main.cpp a.o
```

Running the resulting a.out then gives

```
use count 1
use count 0
value: Hello
```

What is the issue here? Why do I get different results when doing these procedures?

Update: Checking the version of each compiler gives version 8.4.0 for the cross compiler and 8.3.0 for the compiler on raspberry pi

Comment: Because you can not link together two object files produced by different compilers. ABI for C++ is not standardized. Just do not do this, and produce executables by the single toolchain from source.

Comment: I get the same result if I cross compile a shared library liba.so and link with that on the pi. I thought that compiling a library with one compiler and then using it later with another was a quite common use case. Any way to see ahead of time which compiler versions should be compatible?

Comment: @Josteinr • Let me fix that for you "Compiling a **C** library with one **C** compiler and then using it later with another **C** compiler is a quite common use case."  That doesn't apply to **C++**.  To paraphrase Titus Winters regarding C++, "Compile EVERYTHING from source, at the SAME TIME with the SAME COMPILER and the SAME FLAGS."